# Django Generic Relation - error when using postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My model in Django has Generic Relation and I'm using postgres as my DB.
These are my modelsclass

```
Reaction(models.Model):
    object_id = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
    root_obj = GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_id")
    react = models.CharField('Reaction', max_length=10)


class Blog(models.Model):
    headline = models.TextField('headline')
    data = GenericRelation(Reaction)
```

When I'm filter by the GenericRelation (e.g. Blog.objects.filter(react__data=XX) ) I'm getting this error:

```
operator does not exist: integer = text
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I think there is a fix in this link but I'm not sure what to do with it.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16055

Thanks!

Comment: Why is your object_id field a TextField? It should be an IntegerField.

Comment: It works! How stupid of me... Thanks a lot!